# Weird (Loop) behavior when using Spring @TransactionalEventListener to publish event

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, event-handling

I have a weird issue which involves `@TransactionalEventListener` not firing correctly or behavior as expected when triggered by another `@TransactionalEventListener`.

The general flow is:

- AccountService publish an Event (to AccountEventListener)
- AccountEventListener listens for the Event
- Perform some processing and then publish another Event (to MailEventListener)
- MailEventListener listens for the Event and peform some processing

So here's the classes (excerpt).

```
public class AccountService {

    @Transactional
    public User createAccount(Form registrationForm) {

        // Some processing

        // Persist the entity
        this.accountRepository.save(userAccount);

        // Publish the Event
        this.applicationEventPublisher.publishEvent(new RegistrationEvent());
    }
}

public class AccountEventListener {

    @TransactionalEventListener
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public MailEvent onAccountCreated(RegistrationEvent registrationEvent) {

        // Some processing

        // Persist the entity
        this.accountRepository.save(userAccount);

        return new MailEvent();
    }
}

public class MailEventListener {

    private final MailService mailService;

    @Async
    @EventListener
    public void onAccountCreated(MailEvent mailEvent) {

        this.mailService.prepareAndSend(mailEvent);
    }
}
```

This code works but my intention is to use `@TransactionalEventListener` in my `MailEventListener` class. Hence, the moment I change from `@EventListener` to `@TransactionalEventListener` in `MailEventListener` class. The MailEvent does not get triggered.

```
public class MailEventListener {

    private final MailService mailService;

    @Async
    @TransactionalEventListener
    public void onAccountCreated(MailEvent mailEvent) {

        this.mailService.prepareAndSend(mailEvent);
    }
}
```

`MailEventListener` was never triggered. So I went to view [Spring Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.8.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#context-functionality-events-annotation), and it states that `@Async @EventListener` is not support for event that is published by the return of another event. And so I changed to using `ApplicationEventPublisher` in my `AccountEventListener` class.

```
public class AccountEventListener {

    @TransactionalEventListener
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void onAccountCreated(RegistrationEvent registrationEvent) {

        // Some processing

        this.accountRepository.save(userAccount);

        this.applicationEventPublisher.publishEvent(new MailEvent());
    }
}
```

Once I changed to the above, my `MailEventListener` now will pick up the event that is sent from `AccountEventListener` but the webpage hangs when form is submitted and it throws some exception after awhile, and then it also sent me about 9 of the same email to my email account.

I added some logging, and found out that my `AccountEventListener` (`this.accountRepository.save()`) actually ran 9 times before hitting the exception, which then causes my `MailEventListener` to execute 9 times I believe, and that is why I received 9 mails in my inbox.

Here's the logs in [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/sAHckcjc).

I'm not sure why and what is causing it to run 9 times. There is no loop or anything in my methods, be it in `AccountService`, `AccountEventListener`, or `MailEventListener`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So I went to view Spring Documentation, and it states that @Async @EventListener is not support for event that is published by the return of another event. And so I changed to using ApplicationEventPublisher in my AccountEventListener class.

Your understand is incorrect.

[The document said that](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.8.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#context-functionality-events-annotation):

> This feature is not supported for asynchronous listeners.

It does not mean

*it states that @Async @EventListener is not support for event that is published by the return of another event.*

It means:

*This feature does not support events return from @Async @EventListener.*

Your setup:

```
@Async
@TransactionalEventListener
public void onAccountCreated(MailEvent mailEvent) {

    this.mailService.prepareAndSend(mailEvent);
}
```

Does not work [because as stated in document](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/event/TransactionalEventListener.html):

> If the event is not published within the boundaries of a managed transaction, the event is discarded unless the fallbackExecution() flag is explicitly set. If a transaction is running, the event is processed according to its TransactionPhase.

If you use the debug, you can see that if your event is returned from an event listener, it happens after the transaction commit, hence the event is discarded.

So if you set the `fallbackExecution = true` as stated in the document, your event will correctly listened:

```
@Async
@TransactionalEventListener(fallbackExecution = true)
public void onAccountCreated(MailEvent mailEvent) {

    this.mailService.prepareAndSend(mailEvent);
}
```

The repeated behavior is look like some retry behavior, the connection queued up, exhaust the pool and throw the exception. Unless you provide a minimal source code to reproduce the problem, I can't identify it.

**Update**

Reading your code, the root cause is clear now.

Look at your setup for `POST /registerPublisherCommon`

1. `MailPublisherCommonEvent` and `AccountPublisherCommonEvent` are subevent of `BaseEvent`
2. `createUserAccountPublisherCommon` publish an event of type `AccountPublisherCommonEvent`
3. `MailPublisherCommonEventListener` is registered to handle `MailPublisherCommonEvent`
4. `AccountPublisherCommonEventListener` is registered to handle `BaseEvent` and **ALL SUB-EVENT of it**.
5. `AccountPublisherCommonEventListener` also publishes `MailPublisherCommonEvent` (which is also a `BaseEvent`).

Read 4 + 5 you will see the root cause: `AccountPublisherCommonEventListener` publishes `MailPublisherCommonEvent` which is also handled by itself, hence the infinite event processing occur.

To resolve it, simply narrow down the type of event it can handle like you did.

**Note**

Your setup for `MailPublisherCommonEvent` working regardless the `fallbackExecution` flag because you're publishing it `INSIDE A TRANSACTION`, not `OUTSIDE A TRANSACTION` (by return from an event listener) like you specified in your question.

Comment: Hi, thanks for looking over it. I will have a working copy in github later in the day once I get it up.

Comment: Hi, I have setup a git, and actually found out the cause and solution, just not exactly sure of the exact reasoning behind it. if you could take a look at my reply above. Thank you.

Comment: I saw the mistake now. I actually didn't realize that I had set all to the same BaseEvent even after doing the POC which is the cause of the loop. And, yes, I need to be inside the transaction and not outside. Thanks for pointing out to me.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I found out what is causing the looping and how to resolve it but I still cannot understand why does it happens as such.

And correct me if I'm wrong, setting `fallbackExecution = true` isn't really the answer to the issue.

Based on Spring documentation, `the event is processed according to its TransactionPhase.` So I had `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` in my `AccountEventListener` class which should be a transaction by itself, and `MailEventListener` should only be executing in the event that the phase which by default is `AFTER_COMMIT` for `@TransactionalEventListener`.

I setup a git, to reproduce the issue and while doing so, allows me to discover what really went wrong. Having said that, I still do not understand the root cause of it.

Before I do, there are some things that I am not 100% sure but it's just my guess/understand at this moment.

As mentioned in the [Spring Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/event/TransactionalEventListener.html),

> If the event is not published within the boundaries of a managed transaction, the event is discarded unless the fallbackExecution() flag is explicitly set. If a transaction is running, the event is processed according to its TransactionPhase.

And my guess of the reason why `MailEventListener` class did not pick up the event when using the event as the return type to let Spring automatically publish is because it publishes outside of the boundaries of a managed transaction. Which is why, if you set `(fallbackExecution = true)` in `MailEventListener`, it will work/run because it doesn't matter if it in within the transaction or not.

> Note: Classes mentioned above are taken from my initial post. The
>   classes below are named slightly differently but essentially, all are
>   still the same, just different name.

Now, back to the point where I said I found the answer as to why it is causing the loop.
Basically, it is when the parameter put in the listener is a `BaseEvent` of sort.

So assuming that I have the following classes:

```
public class BaseEvent {

    private final User userAccount;

}

public class AccountPublisherCommonEvent extends BaseEvent {

    public AccountPublisherCommonEvent(User userAccount) {
        super(userAccount);
    }

}

public class MailPublisherCommonEvent extends BaseEvent {

    public MailPublisherCommonEvent(User userAccount) {
        super(userAccount);
    }

}
```

And the listeners classes `(Notice that the parameter is the BaseEvent)`:

```
public class AccountPublisherCommonEventListener {

    private final AccountRepository accountRepository;
    private final ApplicationEventPublisher eventPublisher;

    // Notice that the parameter is the BaseEvent
    @TransactionalEventListener
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void onAccountPublisherCommonEvent(BaseEvent accountEvent) {

        User userAccount = accountEvent.getUserAccount();
        userAccount.setUserFirstName("common");

        this.accountRepository.save(userAccount);

        this.eventPublisher.publishEvent(new MailPublisherCommonEvent(userAccount));
    }

}

public class MailPublisherCommonEventListener {

    @Async
    @TransactionalEventListener
    public void onMailPublisherCommonEvent(MailPublisherCommonEvent mailEvent) {

        log.info("Sending common email ...");
    }
}
```

Basically, if the setup of the listener is as such (above), then you enter a loop and hit an exception as mentioned by the previous poster.

> The repeated behavior is look like some retry behavior, the connection queued up, exhaust the pool and throw the exception.

And to resolve the issue, simply, change the input, and define the classes to listen by `(Notice the addition of ({AccountPublisherCommonEvent.class}))`:

```
public class AccountPublisherCommonEventListener {

    private final AccountRepository accountRepository;
    private final ApplicationEventPublisher eventPublisher;

    // Notice the addition of ({AccountPublisherCommonEvent.class})
    @TransactionalEventListener({AccountPublisherCommonEvent.class})
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void onAccountPublisherCommonEvent(BaseEvent accountEvent) {

        User userAccount = accountEvent.getUserAccount();
        userAccount.setUserFirstName("common");

        this.accountRepository.save(userAccount);

        this.eventPublisher.publishEvent(new MailPublisherCommonEvent(userAccount));
    }

}
```

An alternative would be changing the parameter to the actual class name instead of the `BaseEvent` class I suppose. And there is no changes required to the `MailPublisherCommonEventListener`

By doing so, it no longer loop, nor hit the exception. The behavior would run as I want and expected it to.

I would appreciate if anyone could answer to as of why does this happen exactly if I place the `BaseEvent` as the input would caused a looping to occur. Here's the link to [git](https://github.com/bwgjoseph/eventlistener-poc) for the poc. Hope I'm making some sense here.

Thank you.